# how to reinitialise a datatable in the newest version of Tabulator

Tags: tabulator

I would like to reinitialise a data table because the data inside the table has been updated. I noticed that `$('#...').tabulator("destroy")` could be a solution. However, it seems there is no tabulator function in the newest version of Tabulator.

May I ask how to fulfil a function which is the same to `tabulator("destroy")` in the old version?

Comment: If this solution worked please accept the answer or else if you still have issue let me know :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use Destroy it will Destroy the whole Tabulator, use clearData Update and Add as per [documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/update#alter-add).

Check my below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.4/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<body>
<div id="example-table"></div>

<button onclick="removeData()">Clear Data</button>
<button onclick="update()">Update Data</button>


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.4/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<script>


  const tabledata1 = [
    {id: 1, name: "Oli ", money: "0", col: "red", dob: ""},
    {id: 2, name: "Mary ", money: "0", col: "blue", dob: "14/05/1982"},
    {id: 3, name: "Christine ", money: "0", col: "green", dob: "22/05/1982"},
    {id: 4, name: "Brendon ", money: "0", col: "orange", dob: "01/08/1980"},
    {id: 5, name: "Margret ", money: "0", col: "yellow", dob: "31/01/1999"},
  ];

  const tabledata2 = [
    {id: 1, name: " Bob", money: "12", col: "red", dob: ""},
    {id: 2, name: " May", money: "1", col: "blue", dob: "14/05/1982"},
    {id: 3, name: " Lobowski", money: "42", col: "green", dob: "22/05/1982"},
    {id: 4, name: "Brendon ", money: "0", col: "orange", dob: "01/08/1980"},
    {id: 5, name: " Marmajuke", money: "16", col: "yellow", dob: "31/01/1999"},
  ];

  const table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height: 205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
    data: tabledata1, //assign data to table
    layout: "fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
    columns: [ //Define Table Columns
      {title: "Name", field: "name", width: 150},
      {
        title: "money",
        field: "money",
        align: "left",
        formatter: "money"
      },
      {title: "Favourite Color", field: "col"},
      {title: "Date Of Birth", field: "dob", sorter: "date", align: "center"},
    ]
  });

  function removeData() {
    table.clearData();
  }

  function update() {
    table.updateOrAddData(tabledata2);
    // table.addData(tabledata2);
  }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```